# In Javascript why numbers that have leading zeros turn different when logged?

Tags: javascript

When I log the numbers in the array, the oens that have leading zeroes turn to be different:

```
const array = [0123,5202,150,0000015,0202020,1,001,0000000000];
array.forEach(n => {
    console.log(n) // logs this -> 83, 5202, 150, 13, 66576, 1, 1, 0
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a number with leading zeros is an octal number in computer science that means that 010 == 8 and your 00015 == 13 because it is 8 + 5